# Directive @Input variable not getting update when component update the value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to dynamically validate the custom-text-input based on service call result. If its true means jumpyId is available to use otherwise show error. My issue right now is when I update this.isAvailable from fromEvent its not reflecting the value in custom directive.
I am expecting if api call return `true`, then directive should receive `true` otherwise `false`.

**AvailableDirective.ts**

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: 'custom-text-input[vendorAvailable][formControlName],custom-text-input[vendorAvailable][formControl],custom-text-input[vendorAvailable][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: AvailabilityDirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AvailabilityDirective implements Validator {

  @Input('available') available: boolean;
  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    console.log("valid", this.available);
    if (!this.available) {
      return {
        available: false
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**EventObservable:**

```
fromEvent(this.custom.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        return event.target.value;
      })
      , debounceTime(1000)
      , distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe((text: string) => {
      this.myService.isAvailable(text).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res) {
          this.isAvailable = true;
        } else {
          this.isAvailable = false;
        }
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
```

**template:**

```
<custom-text-input *ngIf="drawer"
                                           label="JumpyId"
                                           [(ngModel)]="jumpyId"
                                           id="jumpyId"
                                           name="jumpyId"
                                           required
                                           [available]="isAvailable"
                                           #custom>
                        </custom-text-input>
```

Comment: The problem is not the new value s not received. If you used a setter or an ngOnCHanges, you could easily chck that. The problem is that yu expect the validate method to be called again even though the form control value hasn't changed.

Answer (score 7):

Add an onChanges that watches for changes to available

```
onChange: () => void;

registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if ('available' in changes) {
    if (this.onChange) {
      this.onChange();
    }
  }
}
```

If my validation directives rely on another input I use this validator base

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfexiy

Comment: I learnt something today, thanks. Is there some similar mechanism available when yo want to simply add a validator to a FormControl in a reactive form and want the validator to revalidate if something other than the FormCOntrol value changes (other than revalidating explicitly)?

Comment: Not sure sorry, I only use template forms.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianBrand